# Postgres function WITH in Laravel QueryBuilder

Tags: postgresql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

please help me.

I've got the raw SQL

```
WITH collections AS (
    SELECT 
        ...
    FROM
        ...
)
SELECT
    ...
FROM collections c1
LEFT JOIN collections c2
    ...
```

How I can write it using Laravel QueryBuilder?

Comment: Laravel QueryBuilder does not support `WITH` syntax. You have 2 options: rewrite query without 'WITH' or use DB::select() which accepts raw sql queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the RAW method of Laravel's Query Builder (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#raw-expressions). Just be careful with potential SQL injection loopholes.

Comment: Now I'm doing this:
$queryResult = DB::select("
            with collections AS (
                SELECT .....))";

Comment: Can you post the entire query statement that you made?

Comment: `$queryResult = DB::select("
with collections AS (
  SELECT tcm.shop_id, ...
  FROM template_collection_menu AS tcm
  LEFT JOIN template_collection AS tc ON tc.id =   tcm.template_collection_id
  WHERE tcm.shop_id IN (:mainShopId, :currentShopId)
  ORDER BY tcm.position ASC
)
SELECT
  COALESCE(c2.shop_id, c1.shop_id) as shop_id, ...
  FROM collections c1
  LEFT JOIN collections c2 ON c2.template_collection_id = c1.template_collection_id AND c1.shop_id = :mainShopId AND c2.shop_id = :currentShopId
  WHERE c1.shop_id = :mainShopId
        ", ['mainShopId' => $mainShopId,...]);`

Comment: Have you checked the URL that I gave? You have to use DB::raw instead of DB::select.

Comment: @IlyaPoluhin, you can use the DB::raw like this DB::raw('SELECT * FROM table...)